# Where is the documentation for programming OpenGL ES for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, c++, opengl, c

How can I program an OpenGL ES program for Ubuntu Touch?

I have installed QtCreator and the Ubuntu SDK, but I can't seem to find any documentation about this topic.

Comment: are you looking for this -> http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/documentation/ ?

Comment: no i'm looking for documentation for something similar to glsurfaceview in android , meaning how to create an opengl es view in qtcreator that'll work on ubuntu touch, primarily for games .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the Qt Project site, see:

[Qt OpenGL examples](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/examples-widgets-opengl.html)

[OpenGL Under QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html)

[QtGUI (includes OpenGL and OpenGL ES integration)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtgui-index.html)

These pages provide examples and entry points into the Qt API documentation.

The Ubuntu developer site does not currently have an area specifically about using OpenGL, but you may want to watch the [QML section](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/api/).

Comment: First link is dead :(

Comment: @tshirtman Thanks. I cleaned up the answer (for now).