# It's possible to develop ubuntu touch app in C++ without using QML?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, c++, opengl, sdl

I am looking for way to develop ubuntu touch app using only C/C++.
I want to know what are other options, maybe GTK+ can be used ? or QT Widget ? without sacrificing display touch capabilities ?

And also is there support for SDL/SDL2 and OpenGL on ubuntu touch devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Qt widgets on Ubuntu touch. Tested on bq 4.5 phone.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu definitely has support for Qt, considering that it's built almost entirely using it. QML is the C++ tool that developers use to make the application development easier.

Ubuntu touch has OpenGL support, as you can see [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261468/where-is-the-documentation-for-programming-opengl-es-for-ubuntu-touch/313552#313552)

Comment: thanks for your answer but that is not it, I know that ubuntu touch has Qt libraries, but Ubuntu SDK in Qt Creator wont let you use Qt widgets as a form for Ubuntu touch devices (it says desktop only). So I am asking for non-default ways to make apps entirely in C++, because I consider learning entirely new and differend language(QML) much more difficult than building an app from the scratch in C or C++.